# How to fix this Python python script not to crash when request a offline website?

Tags: python

how to make python still running and show which site is down? and which code to print all the display to txt log file? I'm currently using win 10 and using this code to check the site ip and compare every 6 hours but when one of those site down it will automatic crash:

```
import requests, smtplib, time
    
    urls = ['http://site1.com', 'http://site2.com', 'https://site3.com', 'https://site4.com', 'https://site5.com', 'https://site....com']
    print("Checking websites:", str(urls))
    
    def checkSites():
            while True:
                siteIPs = []
    
                
                for site in urls:
                    request = requests.get(site, stream=True)
                    siteIPs.append([site, request.raw._connection.sock.getpeername()[0]])
                    current_ips = siteIPs
    
                print("Current site IPs:", str(current_ips))
```

Answer (score 1):

import requests, smtplib, time

```
urls = ['http://site1.com', 'http://site2.com', 'https://site3.com', 'https://site4.com', 'https://site5.com', 'https://site....com']
print("Checking websites:", str(urls))

def checkSites():
        while True:
            siteIPs = []

            
            for site in urls:
                try:
                    request = requests.get(site, stream=True)
                except: 
                    print('Site offline')
                siteIPs.append([site, request.raw._connection.sock.getpeername()[0]])
                current_ips = siteIPs

            print("Current site IPs:", str(current_ips))
```

Comment: your code make python not to crash but i need to check which site is down, can you provide more help? thanks

Comment: How do you want to get the information that it is down? Because it prints it on the screen already!